# Android: register app as gamepad input device for dual screen phone

Tags: android

I'm not really sure how easy/realistic this would be to do, but I have an LG G8X that has a dual-screen case similar to the LG v50 and v60. It includes a gamepad app that registers itself as a gamepad so that it can be used with games that support wired/bluetooth controllers.

The included app is pretty lackluster, it only comes with a few gamepads that act as real controllers and the customization only lets you register buttons as touch input at a specific location and not as gamepad input.

I wanted to try messing around with making my own gamepad app, but I'm quickly realizing that apps such as xCloud/xbox streaming require a gamepad recognized device to be paired before you can properly load up a game, so simply adding a button to my app and registering the input as KEYCODE_BUTTON_A won't be enough to work.

Is there any way to make an android app fool the system into thinking there's a Bluetooth or wired gamepad connected?

I'm sorry for the poor tagging, I'm just not sure what the appropriate tags would be outside of android.

Answer (score 2):

I decompiled the LG gamepad and found the method `setEnableVirtualJoystick` in InputManager that I called using reflection. The entire app actually decompiled quite well which no obfuscation which should be able to answer any other questions I might run into too.

Comment: Hi @PaladinoDH, Could you please give me direction on where I can find the LG gamepad APK. I did Google and also search in the XDA, but there was no luck.